# Image Conversion - RAW to png/raw for game (Pac The Man X)

Tags: image, 2d, converters

So I have raw image and I am just curious If I can edit such image to save as RGB-32 Packed transparent interlaced raw and what program I could use, there is specification:
[Format of RAW image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7caz.png)

I have tried using photoshop but then game crashes. Is it even possible? I should get file without thumbnail. I also tried using gimp, free converters and Raw viewer but no luck. Any suggestions?

Edit:
Used photoshop (interleaved with transparency format), game starts but images are just bunch of pixels.

[file that i try to prepare (221bits)](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1bhR8gAz88f6-mIys3G0EoQgsjka1pwkR?usp=sharing)

Comment: I can probably answer your question if you clarify it. What format is your image currently in and what format you want it in? At the moment it says you have a raw image and you want a raw image - so you already have what you want, surely? The image you shared is 221196 bytes, so if that is RGBA we must divide it by 4 to get the number of pixels, meaning there are 55299 pixels, which means your image can only be 18433x3 pixels (since those are the divisors) but that seems an unlikely shape. So, please clarify height, width and format of `ghost.raw` and what format you want it converted to.

Comment: It may be 512x512 but is seems to render properly as 512x108-112.

Answer (score 1):

We are still not getting a handle on what output format you are really trying to achieve. Let's try generating a file from scratch, to see if we can get there.

So, let's just use simple commands that are available on a Mac and generate some test images from first principles. Start with **exactly** the same `ghost.raw` image you shared in your question. We will take the first 12 bytes as the header, and then generate a file full of red pixels and see if that works:

```
# Grab first 12 bytes from "ghost.raw" and start a new file "red.raw"
head -c 12 ghost.raw > red.raw

# Now generate 512x108 pixels, where red=ff, green=00, blue=01, alpha=fe and append to "red.raw"
perl -E 'say "ff0001fe" x (512*108)' | xxd -r -p >> red.raw
```

So you can try using `red.raw` in place of `ghost.raw` and tell me what happens.

Now try generating a blue file just the same:

```
# Grab first 12 bytes from "ghost.raw" and start a new file "blue.raw"
head -c 12 ghost.raw > blue.raw

# Now generate 512x108 pixels, where red=00, green=01, blue=ff, alpha=fe and append to "blue.raw"
perl -E 'say "0001fffe" x (512*108)' | xxd -r -p >> blue.raw
```

And then try `blue.raw`.

---

**Original Answer**

AFAIK, your image is actually 512 pixels wide by 108 pixels tall in RGBA8888 format with a 12-byte header at the start - making 12 + 4*(512 * 108) bytes.

You can convert it to PNG or JPEG with **ImageMagick** like this:

```
magick -size 512x108+12 -depth 8 RGBA:ghost.raw result.png
```

[image]

I still don't understand from your question or comments what format you actually want - so if you clarify that, I am hopeful we can get you answered.

Comment: hmm it seems to work (from photoshop) only when it's 8 bit, sth like that. Will try this image and conversion method but I have doubts about this as maybe its a bitmap code changed for game purpose. Game uses raw files and as pointed below images from photoshop appear in grayscale and weirdly.

Comment: and how to convert back to raw (12 byte header, RGBA8888, 8 bit, 4 * (512 * 108)) ??? Also I need Mac OS X format not Windows and need to do it under Windows vm cuz imagemagick seem to not work on Mac Pro.

Comment: I get magick: unexpected end-of-file 'ghost.png': No such file or directory @ error/rg
b.c/ReadRGBImage/247 while trying to convert into raw file.

Comment: This is how its displayed in game after converting back https://i.stack.imgur.com/soZJ3.png  magick -size 512x512+12 -depth 32 ghost.png RGBA:ghost.raw. Do I need use sRGB or sth???

Comment: You still haven't explained what you are trying to do, nor what format you need the output to be in. You just keep saying it doesn't work and introducing new obstacles/issues like *"ImageMagick doesn't work on Mac"* and *"No luck with Photoshop"*. What format do you want the result in please?

Comment: The ghost.raw image is from the game Pac The Man X and I want to replace ghost with my own images. First I need to get proper png file (which seems to be that in rawpixels.net, 512x512). I need it to be converted back into 4*(512x512)+12, 8 bit, Mac RGBA Raw file. Tried saving with photoshop 7.0, CS4, Imagemagick conversion (same result as CS4 using command above). magick -size 512x108+12 -depth 8 RGBA:ghost.png (your file) ghost.raw = game can't load raw bitmap, 512x512+12 -depth 32 RGBA:ghost.png (rawpixels.net) ghost.raw = image above. How to make at least different hue than pacman sprite?

Comment: Original ghost.raw after this procedure can't be loaded. There are imagemagick, blue 512x512:https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuMae.png, imagemagick, red 512x512:https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sgRW.png, original, say only, red, 512x108:https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8fUD.png, original, say only, blue, 512x512:https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSBHc.png

Answer (score 0):

Try using online converters. They help most of the time.\

A Website like these can possibly help:

```
https://www.freeconvert.com/raw-to-png
https://cloudconvert.com/raw-to-png
https://www.zamzar.com/convert/raw-to-png/
```

Some are specific websites which ask you for detail and some are straight forward conversions.

Comment: Well and then how to save as raw ??? I get just bunch of pixels rendered.

Comment: Do you want to convert it to a png and save it as a raw?

Comment: I need to save edited png (raw to png image) as raw so it shown properly in game, it displays properly in rawpixels (I think) but cant get it to work. I attached file that I am working on.

Comment: Have you tried png to raw conversions? you take your editied .png file and put it in a converter and it should set it to raw.

Comment: Try converting the raw to png. then from png to raw again? i guess that's basically it. if not then i don't quiet fully understand what you mean.

Comment: tried XnConverter. No luck. Images from photoshop appear in grayscale without proper transparency via differ.

Comment: Then it's probably not possible what you're searching for. or maybe it is but takes some time. Sorry i couldn't help out much.

Comment: maybe I need to use old version of photoshop to get proper raw file? like 6.0?